# How to use prism scoped RegionManager in a modular app?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, plugin-architecture

In the prism docs a scoped `RegionManager` is created somehow like this:

```cs
IRegion detailsRegion = this.regionManager.Regions["DetailsRegion"];
View view = new View();
bool createRegionManagerScope = true;
IRegionManager detailsRegionManager = detailsRegion.Add(view, null, 
                            createRegionManagerScope);
```

I have a modular app in which the **view** is located in **another module**, and the **region** is in the **main assembly**. There are regions in every module that I want them to have the **same view**, that **same view** is located in the main assembly then. This drawing may explain it better:

[image]

So if I want to use the `region.Add` method in a module, I can't instantiate the view because it's located in the main assembly.

Another way I thought of was to use view discovery, i.e. using `RegisterViewWithRegion(string regionName, Type viewType)`, because I can call this method in the main assembly where I have access to `viewType`, and use the `regionName` I passed to this method in the modules. But the problem is I can't have regions with the same name in the modules.

I ended up doing what I have written in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66692262/12960511), But my manager is saying that I'm violating MVVM by creating the `RegionManager` in the view-model.

What is the right way to use scoped `RegionManager` in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

First, a *module* has nothing to do with a *view* - a module is a late-bound, interchangable part of the software.

> So if I want to use the `region.Add` method in a module, I can't instantiate the view because it's located in the main assembly.

You don't call `new`, anyway, because the container does it for you.

So you inject a factory into the class that wants to create the view (the simplest way being a `Func<View>`), and the class uses the factory to create the view. In this case it doesn't matter at all, where the view's or the factory's code resides, as long as you have interfaces (that's a different thing than an `interface`, although an `interface` sitting in a third assembly that itself doesn't belong to any module is common) in place that the modules can use to talk to each other.